# Is +Defense or +Evade a better Leader ability?

Tags: star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes

In Galaxy of Heroes, some characters have Leader abilities. Some of them have the same type of bonus but for different aspects.

For instance:

- Talia and Daka will both provide Nightsisters with some bonus. But what bonus is more powerful? Evade (Talia) or Defense (Daka)?
- Luminara's Evade or Eeth's Defense?

What I'm looking for is not a opinion on what power you prefer :) I want to know what power will result in a better benefit for my team.

I.e., *"Defense is useless, use Talia to evade better"* or *"Eeth's Defense bonus is too low, use Luminara instead."*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Defense is useless, use Talia to evade better :P

---

**Evasion** is like both Dodge Rating and Deflection Rating, whereas [**Defense** adds Armor and Resistance](https://forums.galaxy-of-heroes.starwars.ea.com/discussion/13688/worst-leaders-you-can-get).  The latter work [like so](https://forums.galaxy-of-heroes.starwars.ea.com/discussion/13982/what-does-defence-mean-work-of-some-stats):

```
Mitigation = DefensiveStat / (DefensiveStat + Level*10)
```

So let's say I'm using an all-Jedi team with Luminara (so they all get her full bonus).  My level 61 Lumi has *Elegant Steps* at level 3, which grants 12% Evasion.  So, on average, that's a 12% decrease in incoming damage.  Let's solve the above equation:

```
0.12         = D / (D + 61*10)
0.12D + 73.2 = D
D           ~= 83.2
```

So Eeth would need to grant more than 83 Defense in order to match Lumi's bonus.  This is much lower than his actual bonus (level 6 of *Stalwart Jedi Defender* [only grants 55](http://www.swgohcantina.com/hero-stats/)).

You can apply this same formula to other characters' Evade/Defense bonuses but I believe **Evade always comes out ahead** if you are using an optimal team.

If you're using a fully decked out level 70 Lumi with a non-Jedi team, that's 13% for her and 6.5% for 4 others, or an average of 7.8%.  To match that, Eeth needs to grant about 59.2 Defense, which is closer to his max of 55 but he is still falling quite short since he only gives half of that to non-Jedi.

Note, though, that Armor/Resistance *always apply*, to every incoming attack.  That removes some randomness from the outcome, which you might prefer.  It's always nice in those matches where you get lucky and get a couple more Evades than you expected, but it's equally frustrating when you get fewer!

Comment: I would give you 5 upvotes if I could! Awesome calculation to rationalize the decision. 1 single suggestion: move the TL;DR to the first line :)

Comment: Deciding between evading and defense will also depend on how much burst damage is prevalent and your capabilities at healing (which itself is a reflection of the team you're up against). If you can add enough defense to dependably survive some burst damage, then that's ideal since it gives you an opportunity to consistently respond. If adding defense doesn't really alter your chances of surviving burst damage, then evasion is probably preferred. So, defense could be better, even at lower amounts, *in some situations*. But it's tough to definitively know for sure.

Comment: @Ellesedil I definitely agree with that.  A 100% chance of surviving with ~10% health can be better than an 85% chance of surviving with ~20% health, and so on.

Comment: That's exactly the scenario I was trying to describe. It's a pretty typical "effective health" topic, prevalent in MMORPG's and the like.

Comment: So what about having Chewie as a leader where, in addition to his +Defence, he causes toons to frequently gain a Defence Up buff?

Comment: @intuited I don't the exact numbers offhand, but I believe it's still weaker except for characters like Fives that have a high Defense stat already (and thus benefit proportionally more from the % boost).